# How to Assign Connection String to ChangePassword control in ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I have distributed data base system and in my project data base connection string is in session object. The problem is how to assign connection string to **ChangePassword** control on Runtime from session object.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ChangePassword control works in Conjunction with MembershipProviders**. MembershiProvider of your project holds the configuration of database connectivity [and much more].

You can visit any of the links below to get started with Login Controls and MembershipProviders. ASP.net ships with basic inbuilt Providers.

Here are some links for your reference, which will guide you through what you need.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx
- http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/login.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-7420.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-148.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-47.aspx